# How to obtain first Friday from a given QDate?

Tags: qt, qdate

Consider a `Qdate` from

```
QDate Mydate = ui->dateEdit->date();
```

For example, suppose we choose `2018/07/14` (today).

How to obtain the day of the first Friday (in this case, 6) on the chosen month (in this case, July)?

I suspect we have to use `Mydate.dayOfWeek()` computations.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nick In my case, Friday is 5th day of week. So I tried to test if `Mydate.dayOfWeek()` is `5` or not. Then, I got lost when `Mydate.day()` is greater than the first Friday (like today, 14). I was not able to decide when stop subtracting from `14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a neater solution, but:

1. Subtract dayOfWeek for current date/day from dayOfMonth.
2. Add 5 (for Friday).
3. If -ve add 7 or if +ve answer is modulus 7.

Code:

```
dayOfWeekToday = MyDate.dayOfWeek()
firstFriday = MyDate.day() - dayOfWeekToday + 5
firstFriday = (firstFriday <= 0) ? firstFriday + 7 : firstFriday % 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Nick's answer, there needs to be a special case where result of `MyDate.day() - dayOfWeekToday + 5` is divisible by 7. Something like:

```
dayOfWeekToday = MyDate.dayOfWeek()
firstFriday = MyDate.day() - dayOfWeekToday + 5
firstFriday = (firstFriday <= 0) ? firstFriday + 7 
                                 : (firstFriday % 7 == 0) ? 7 : firstFriday % 7
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30280270)